# node tools for visual studio profiling: v8 log file was not saved, no data

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, profiling

My node application (lots of db access) is running slow, so I want to profile what might be the problem.

I am using Node Tools for Visual Studio current version (1.0 Beta 3) in VS 2013. When starting via the "Analyze"->"Launch Node.js Profiling", I am getting following error and no profiling results:

```
v8 log file was not successfuly saved to:
c:\users\andi\documents\project\v8.log
No profiling data is available.
```

How can I get profiling data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: profiling settings]

Turns out it is not that difficult, similar to [How to debug node.js application with Visual Studio 2013 and Node Tools NTVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554093/how-to-debug-node-js-application-with-visual-studio-2013-and-node-tools-ntvs) . The profiling option needs to be set by hand.

I suppose I will see that I change my application to use app.js for startup, since this seems to (right now) be more compatible with VS.