# Node.JS debugger listening on 5858 port

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio

I have create a simple Node.JS project in Visual Studio 2015. I have add one simple line with code:

```
console.log('Run!')
```

When I run my app (F5), I will see a console window with text: 
"Debugger listening on 5858 port" 
"Run"

As I understand the first line mean that some Node debugger was run, but I do not need it, I use Visual Studio. How can I delete this first messages?

Best regards.

Comment: You can take reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554093/how-to-debug-node-js-application-with-visual-studio-2013-and-node-tools-ntvs

Comment: Unfortunately, this article does not give an answer on my questions. I do not fill a debugger port field in property window.

Answer (score 1):

if you run your app with visual studio (vs). vs will add --debug-brk option automatically and this cause the message "Debugger listening on xxxx port".

this option allow you to set break point at any line of your code to debug it.

if you don't want this, you can run your app using terminal with the command

```
node index.js
```